# restricting of Sftp users setup

Tags: linux, sftp

i have created an sftp user and he is only restricted to use his own home directory but when the user connects using filezilla he still can see other users listed he cant access the other directories but he can still see them..is there a way to restrict the user to only see his home directory.

Comment: i have already completed those steps its just when the user connects with sftp he lands in / instead /home/username is there a way i can force it to land on /home/username

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes